# Grails 2.5.4 auto reloading not working

Tags: java, grails-2.0, grails-controller, intellij-14, spring-loaded

I am working with **grails version 2.5.4.** My application is running fine for me but I can't get any change or update if I **change my controller code**. I am using Intellij Idea 14. When I run my application my code is as below:

```
def index() {
    render "Hello world..."
}
```

Then after I change my code as below:

```
def index() {
        render "Hello world...Update"
}
```

I can't get update details on render with **"Hello world...Update"** text

Comment: is your problem is solved or not

Comment: No still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need put in your config.groovy file below configuration  set reload gsp to true.

```
grails.gsp.enable.reload = true
```

For more details:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2015/11/grails-goodness-enable-hot-reloading.html

Comment: @Piyush is it working for you i'm waiting for response .Thank you !

Comment: I tried it still issue not resolved. I want to do console println and it's not working.

Comment: grails -Dgrails.env=custom -Dgrails.reload.enabled=true run-app try this command

Comment: grails.reload.enabled = true
grails.project.fork = [
        test: false,
        run: false,
]
    please disable fork in your config groovy.

Comment: I refer the documentation (http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/upgradingFrom22.html) but some how I am not able to fix this issue. you are working with Grails 2.5.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally random, but I had the exact same problem, but mine suddenly appeared. It had been working for years, but then suddenly last week it stopped working.

The reason? Well, I had tidied up my disk and moved/renamed some files, and in doing so I had a folder which had a space in it's name. (ie all my projects were in a folder called \apps\grails\ and I then tidied things up so I had \apps\grails 2.1.1\  and \apps\grails 2.5.6\ etc.

As soon as I removed the spaces (so instead, I had \apps\grails2.5.6) - bingo! It started working again.